# Generating discrete signal on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a `constant signal x[n] = 1 for n = 1, 2, 3 and x[n] = 0 otherwise` using **matlab**.

```
N = -5:1:5;
X = -5:1:5;
i = 1;
for n = N
   if (n >= 1 && n <= 3)
     X[i] = 1;
   else
     X[i] = 0;
   end
   i = i + 1;
end
```

But it does not work. I am really new using Matlab for discrete signals, so any help would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: "It does not work" is not helpful. Could you please include what you see and what you expect to see? On issue could be that `X` is not initialized.

Comment: I initialized `X`, but I get the error "Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket." when I do `X[i] = 1`. Why is it wrong?

Comment: @ViníciusLopesSimões Because MATLAB uses `()` for indexing, not `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a `for` iteration in this case. You can accomplish the same using an indexed approach as follows:

```
N1 = -5:5;

X1 = zeros(1,numel(N1));
X1(N1 >= 1 & N1 <= 3) = 1

N2 = -8:2;

X2 = zeros(1,numel(N2));
X2(N2 >= 1 & N2 <= 3) = 1

N3 = 1:11;

X3 = zeros(1,numel(N3));
X3(N3 >= 1 & N3 <= 3) = 1
```

This will output:

```
X1 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0

X2 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1

X3 =
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```